# Nivo Lightbox function in Ajax loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm having trouble making jquery function to work in AJAX loaded content. Function is for adding additional youtube parameters to src link. I'm using Nivo Lightbox for youtube links. This code works fine in not dynamically loaded content:

```
$('.video_btn_slider').nivoLightbox({
     afterShowLightbox: function(lightbox){
        var src = $('.nivo-lightbox-content > iframe').attr('src');        
        $('.nivo-lightbox-content > iframe').attr('src', src + '?autoplay=1'+'&showinfo=0'+'&rel=0');
     }   
});
```

I managed to make it work only wrapping it with:

```
$(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {...});
```

But `DOMNodeInserted` is deprecated.

Therefore, need your advice. Maybe in general there is a better solution.